# Plotting a 3D surface based on a condition

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-3dplot

I want to plot the function

$$f(x,y) = e^{-\frac{1}{1 - |x^2 + y^2|}}$$

but only for the values where $|x^2 + y^2| < 1$, how can I do this?

According to GeoGebra, the plot should look something like this:
[image]

So far this is my code, there are no conditions imposed so it shows everything outside the region I want, where the function behaves really weird. (I know that in the code the $x$ and $y$ values are being taken between -0.5 and 0.5 and that wouldn't show the full plot).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  xmin=-2,
  xmax=2,
  ymin=-2,
  ymax=2,
  zmax=1.5,
  axis lines=middle,
    ]
    \addplot3[
      domain=-0.5:0.5,
      domain y = -0.5:0.5,
      surf,
      samples=10
    ]
    {e^(-1 / (1 - abs(x^2 + y^2)) ) };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is what the graph looks like right now.

[image]

Comment: It is not needed to take `abs` of a positive real number. When using PGFPlots, you should always set `compat` level - see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a polar reparametrization of the plot:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=bevel]
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-2, xmax=2,
ymin=-2, ymax=2,
zmin=0, zmax=1,
xtick={-2,-1,1,2},
xticklabels={-2,,,2},
axis lines=middle,
z buffer=sort,
]
\addplot3[
surf,
variable=a, domain=0:360,
variable y=r, domain y=0:1,
samples=21,
] ( {r*cos(a)} , {r*sin(a)} , {e^(-1/(1-r^2)} );
\draw (0,0,{e^(-1)}) -- (0,0,0.5);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Dome shaped surface plot]